# Python 2.7: TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument - when connecting to Network devices using Netmiko

Tags: python

Python Version - 2.7

Library Used - Netmiko, ConnectHandler is imported  from Netmiko

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
```

The actual code used by Netmiko to connect to devices without any function, this works fine if I dont add this to function:

```
connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=key, username=username, password=password)
output = connect.send_command('terminal length 0', expect_string=r'#')
output = connect.send_command('enable', expect_string=r'#')
host_name = connect.send_command('show run | in hostname', expect_string=r'#')
```

I have tried to add the above code into a function named connection so it can be called at multiple places:

Below is the code that I tried to connect to Network devices using Netmiko, instead of writing the code separately I added the Netmiko connection code to a function that takes in arguments, however after the execution of first line in the function with arguments, the second line has a different command that does not need any arguments from the function itself:

```
def connection(platform, key, username, password):
    connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=key, username=username, password=password)
    output = connect.send_command('terminal length 0', expect_string=r'#')
    output = connect.send_command('enable', expect_string=r'#')
    host_name = connect.send_command('show run | in hostname', expect_string=r'#')
    return connect, host_name, output

connection('cisco_xe', key , user, pass)
```

For example the first line that connects to the device needs four arguments ('cisco_xe', key , user, pass) that worked without issue. In the second line the argument expect_string=r'#' is required by the command, however I get the following error when the second
`(output = connect.send_command('terminal length 0', expect_string=r'#')` line is executed:

```
TypeError: commandStatus() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expect_string'
```

Comment: Please show the entire traceback.

Comment: Your error is not consistent with your code? Error mentions commandStatus(), but I don't see commandStatus anywhere?

Comment: @KirkByers, actually I have a script that connects to network devices and gets output of interface and BGP status and sends mail. The whole script is written without any functions. Now, I am trying to cleanup the code by adding functions to reduce the repeated number of code lines. Whenever I call a variable that is defined within function I get the error:```NameError: name 'host_name' is not defined```

Comment: This is the part of code below.  ```def connection(platform, key, username, password):
 global connect
 global host_name
 global output
 from netmiko import ConnectHandler
 connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=key, username=username, password=password)
 output = connect.send_command('terminal length 0', expect_string=r'#')
 output = connect.send_command('enable', expect_string=r'#')
 host_name = connect.send_command('show run | in hostname', expect_string=r'#')
 return connect, host_name, output```

Comment: ```def int_brief():
 from netmiko import ConnectHandler
 global commandOutput
 commandOutput = connect.send_command('show ip int brief',expect_string=r'#')
 shell = redirect_shell()
 return commandOutput, shell```

Comment: ```for key, value in interfaces.items():
 actualdevice = key
 if actualdevice in {'device1', 'device2'}:
  print(actualdevice)
  connection('cisco_xe', key , faivty_user, faivty_pass)
  print(host_name)
  print(commandOutput)```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to maintain the python indentation, but its not working in the comments

Comment: You need to post the above as code (i.e. just add it/append it to your original posting).